# Does Devexpress GridControl for win forms support paging?

Tags: c#, paging, devexpress

Does Devexpress GridControl for win forms support paging? If yes, how does it work? How can i use paging to show some data in a grid control? Any example would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't support paging, per se, it loads the records as needed when running in servermode if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont actually think the WinForms version of the grid does support paging. The ASP.NET version of the grid does support it - I've been using it a lot lately.

Someone has asked the [question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S91343.aspx?searchtext=paging&p=T4|P1|56) on the DevExpress support centre. It doesnt look like they are going to be implementing 'out of the box' paging on WinForms. It looks like you are going to have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well the paging is not supported by DevExpress XtraGrid.

You will find at the following [page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ14218.aspx) some hints given by DevExpress Staffs to implement your own paging.