# Devexpress WinForms Grid's data with Paging like aspxGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using `Devexpress`.

Is there's any way to get `WinsForm GridView` ,data with page by page(Paging) like `aspGridView`. The problem is I want to bind 10 rows per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer:** [How to create paging on XtraGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q344827)

> GridControl does not support the paging mechanism natively. You can
>   introduce this feature by using [XPPageSelector](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/clsDevExpressXpoXPPageSelectortopic) , as shown in the
>   How to use the XPPageSelector with the GridControl example.
>
> If your task is to load large data volumes in a grid, the best choice
>   in this scenario would be to use a [Server Mode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398) .

References:
[Simple Paging in XtraGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S139572)
[Paging feature for XtraGrid control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q336397)
[Paging in Devexpress XtraGrid GrdiControl for Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859346/paging-in-devexpress-xtragrid-grdicontrol-for-windows-application)
[Does Devexpress GridControl for win forms support paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113305/does-devexpress-gridcontrol-for-win-forms-support-paging)

Comment: Thank sir.It works but how can i use `XPServerCollectionSource` with stored procedure.Thanks

Comment: Most of links so old about 4 or 5 years ago, has XtraGrid yet this weakness as older version?!